# webpack not uglifying js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

This I think seems to stem from not fully understanding webpack, but I want to export a minified file with all my imports into one file. My config looks like this:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  // entry is already defined in gulpfile.js - leave this line commented out.
  // entry: "/app/js/script.js",
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query  :{
          presets:['react','es2015']
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true, mangle: true }),
  ],
};
```

The main focus for me now is this line:

`new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true, mangle: true }),`

My output script file looks like this:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };
...and it goes on
```

When I want it to be a minified file so it looks more something like:

console.log("I'm here!"),$(function(){$(".expander").click(function(){"block"!=$(this).children(".indented").css("display")?($(this).children(".indented").css("display","block"),$(this).children(".caret").addClass("reversedCaret")):($(this).children(".indented").css("display","none"),$(this).children(".caret").removeClass("reversedCaret"))}),$(".sub-expander, .caret").click(function(){"More"!=$(".sub-expander").text()?$(".sub-expander").text("More"):$(".sub-expander").text("Show Less")}),$(".indented").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()})});

Also, I have the uglify plugin install confirmed:

```
new_platform_prototype@1.0.0 /projects/new-platform-prototype

└── uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
```

Am I missing something about a core concept of webpack? Why can't I get a minified export of all my includes? Isn't that the whole point of Webpack?

Comment: Is `NODE_ENV` set to `production`?

Comment: In my webpack config?

Comment: Just in your environment, generally. Note the first line of your config file sets `debug` to `true` or `false`. Is it setting it to true and skipping the uglify?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I'm still working on getting a better understanding of everything. But this is helpful and makes sense. So it looks like in the project I should change the environment variable to production to get minified builds without all the webpack references in the output?

Comment: Yes. `NODE_ENV` is an environment variable that will not be set to anything by default, which, in your case, will result in a `debug` value of true.

Comment: I tried changing the `NODE_ENV` in webpack config to `var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";` but I get `TypeError: webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin is not a constructor` so i went into both index.js files where `NODE_ENV` is defined and changed it directly there to true but it's still not minifying or stripping out the webpack references...

Comment: Just try `var debug = false;` at the top of your webpack config and see if that gets what you want.

Comment: why don't you use grunt instead? with webpack and uglify

Comment: https://github.com/SapienML/template/blob/master/Gruntfile.js this is how I did. I bundled with webpack and then used grunt to run uglify task after build.

Comment: @crook I'm using gulp FWIW for this so maybe I can do an uglify task within gulp

Comment: yup. you can try that.

Comment: that works well for me so I will leave it at that